# Adding a Second GPU to my motherboard and Getting black screen on Startup

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, desktop-computer, pci-express, cryptomining

So, I tried connecting a second GPU, a GTX 1060 6GB to the second PCIEx16 slot via Riser cable USB in my MSI b550 Tomahawk mobo, and when I turn on my computer I just get a black screen and the VGA ez-debug light pops on, and can't get into the BIOS. My main GPU is a 2070Super powered in the first PCIE x16 slot. When I unplug the second gpu thats in the riser cable, my PC turns on and runs fine/ no debug light and goes through BIOS. What could be going wrong with adding the second GPU? I have not tried connecting the GPU without the riser cable and turning my PC on.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may need a beefier power supply to handle a second GPU. My father got an RTX 2090(?) and needed a better power supply for the system to be able to use his video cards.

EDIT: A second GPU would definitely need a better Power Supply. GPU's use up a lot of power, and having 2 may outrun your power supply's abilities.

Comment: I have EVGA 750w GOLD+ PSU. Shouldnt that be enough? the 1060 only uses 120w of power at Max wattage

Answer (score 0):

Could be something wrong with the riser. Try connecting the card into the slot and see if it works. It should also be noted that, since the cards are different, you will not be able to use them in sync to boost framerate.

As WG481 mentioned, it could be the PSU: what's the power output?

EDIT: are you trying to connect the cards to the same monitor?

Comment: I have a 750w Gold EVGA power supply. that should be more than enough I believe. and No i have 2 monitors connected to the 2070super, I am trying to use the second GPU to mine. I didnt want the second GPU to be inside my PC, so thats why I bought the mining Riser